# Recalculation of exchanges done twice

Tags: brightway

When using the function ParameterManager.recalculate() to get the actualised values of all the parameterized exchanges of my database, the functions ActivityParameter.recalculate() and ActivityParameter.recalculate_exchanges() are applied to all the parameters groups. But it seems that the function ActivityParameter.recalculate_exchanges() is ran twice because it is also used inside the function ActivityParameter.recalculate(). When deleting one, I get the same results but twice faster (that is what I was looking for because otherwise my calculation is a bit long). Is there a reason for running the function twice ? Is it right to delete one to get faster results ? Would there be a way to reduce the duration of this calculation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally right - `ParameterManager.recalculate` calls both [`ActivityParameter.recalculate` and `ActivityParameter.recalculate_exchanges`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/blob/cccc21650e2e2cee1553fb97ae7b1f9d8f964403/bw2data/parameters.py#L1612), but `ActivityParameter.recalculate` [already calls `ActivityParameter.recalculate_exchanges`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/blob/cccc21650e2e2cee1553fb97ae7b1f9d8f964403/bw2data/parameters.py#L831). This makes things slower, but doesn't break anything.

This duplication [has been removed](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/commit/948d48bcb608ae4cc7525a0c8696495c74da0b76); you can safely do the same.